# Connection Timed out issue while consuming REST API service

Tags: spring, webclient, microservices, reactive

I have developed a microservice using Reactive WebFlux of Spring 5. In this, using webClient, I'm trying to consume another REST API service. Everything works fine when I'm using my personal home network however I always get connection timed out error whenever I try to consume this same REST service using my microservice while working in my office. 
I suspect it has something to do with the firewall or proxy in my office network. I have already disabled the windows firewall in my machine but still not working. Any advise on this issue.

Following is the code snippet:

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    public TweetController(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        this.webClient = webClientBuilder.baseUrl("https://mockapi.demo.com").build();
    }

    @GetMapping("/get-customers")
    public Mono<String> someRestCall(String name) {
        System.out.println("****************** /get-customers *******************");
        return this.webClient
                .get()
                .uri("/catalogs")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);
    }
```

Error:

> **ERROR 17996 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] .a.w.r.e.DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler : Failed to handle request
>   [GET http://localhost:8080/get-customers]
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection
>   timed out: no further information: test.usdemo.xyz.com/92.54.41.24:443
>   at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171] at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_171] at
>   io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:325)
>   ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final] at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
>   ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final] at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633)
>   ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final] at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
>   ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final] at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
>   ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final] at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
>   ~[netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final] at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
>   ~[netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar:4.1.24.Final] at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_171] Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further
>   information ... 10 common frames omitted**

Comment: is it up and running on: http://localhost:8080/get-customers ? can you curl it or open it in your browser?

Comment: no, i get same exception on browser for localhost:8080/get-customers when i try inside my office network. i get successfully json response when im using the home network.

Comment: But if you access this from your browser? https://mockapi.demo.com